# How do I deal with Named Handler Methods using the Fetch API in my ASP.Net Razor Pages app?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, fetch-api, razor-pages

I'm using an inline Fetch API script to upload files to a storage server. Here's the simple HTML which allows me to choose a file.

```
<form method="post" class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="UploadedFile" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input asp-for="UploadedFile" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 offset-sm-3">
            <button asp-page-handler="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the fetch script I'm using to make a client side request to send file to storage.

```
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let data = new FormData(document. Forms[0]);
    fetch(' ', {
        method: 'post',
        body: data
    })
        .then(() => {
            alert('File Uploaded');
        });
});
```

This final piece of code is the actual handler which does some simple processing on the incoming file.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(IFormFile uploadedFile)
    {
        IFormFile? uploadedFormFile = uploadedFile;

        if (uploadedFormFile.Length > 0)
        {
            string? filePath = Path.Combine(_databaseUploadPath, uploadedFormFile.FileName);

            using (FileStream? databaseStream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
            {
                databaseStream.Position = 0;
                await uploadedFormFile.CopyToAsync(databaseStream);
            }
        }
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Now, this works absolutely fine when the handler function is named `OnPost` but how do I get this to work if I rename the function to something like `OnPostUpload`? I want to make use of **named handlers** as shown [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods)

My usual approach when working with a basic static site is by using the `asp-page-handler=...` tag on the button to specify a handler, which doesn't work, so I assume I need to actually specify it inside the fetch API script as detailed above.

How do I specify a specific endpoint handler when firing off a fetch request on the client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My usual approach when working with a basic static site is by using
> the asp-page-handler=... tag on the button to specify a handler, which
> doesn't work, so I assume I need to actually specify it inside the
> fetch API script as detailed above.
>
> How do I specify a specific endpoint handler when firing off a fetch
> request on the client side?

Well, based on your shared code snippet and description, I have couple of findings regarding why your handler not ended up with the expected result,

First of all, you are using handler in button whereas you would use that within  from attribute like `form asp-page-handler="HandlerName"`

Another point is that, while uploading file, you should define type as file and name attribute which would be mapped with your IFormFile property name. For instance, `type="file" name="uploadedFile"` which are also missing within snippet.

Most importantly, for uploading file within `form` you should define `enctype="multipart/form-data">` otherwise, your file will be null in backend.

Finally, on button submit event you can simply use, `onclick="this.form.submit();"` which will submit your form, so that you no longer need to use `Id` HTML attribute in order to listen click event.

Let's have a look in practice, how we can do that in razor page.

CSHTML.CS:

```cs
public class UploadPageHandlerModel : PageModel
    {


        public IFormFile? uploadedFile { get; set; }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUpload(IFormFile uploadedFile)
        {
            IFormFile? uploadedFormFile = uploadedFile;

            if (uploadedFormFile.Length > 0)
            {
                
            }
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
    }
```

CSHTML:

```
@page
@model RazorPageDemoApp.Pages.UploadPageHandlerModel
@{
}

<form method="post" class="col-sm-6" asp-page-handler="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="uploadedFile" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input asp-for="uploadedFile"  type="file" name="uploadedFile" accept="image/*" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 offset-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="this.form.submit();">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Using Fetch API:**

I have modified your HTML files as following and moved the handler on top of Form attribute:

```
<form method="post" class="col-sm-6" asp-page-handler="Upload" >
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="uploadedFile" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input asp-for="uploadedFile" name="uploadedFile" type="file" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 offset-sm-3">
            <button  class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now for fetch API, you should pass the URL along with handler name as following order with the additional header value in order to avoid 400 bad request:

```
@section Scripts
    {
    <script>

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
            evt.preventDefault();

            async function uploadFileToRazorPage(formData) {
                try {
                    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5062/UploadPageHandler?handler=Upload", {
                        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": document.querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value },
                        method: "POST",
                        body: formData,
                    });
                    const result = await response.json();
                    console.log("Success:", result);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Error:", error);
                }
            }

            const formData = new FormData();
            const fileField = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');


            formData.append("uploadedFile", fileField.files[0]);

            uploadFileToRazorPage(formData);
        });
        
    </script>
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:**  Please [have look at the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#upload-small-files-with-buffered-model-binding-to-physical-storage) if you need any further details.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Farid. I've made the adjustments you advised to the HTML and then re-wrote the Fetch API section. It's correctly going though to my named handler function now and uploading the file.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback mate, glad to know that it has helped you to make that work.